# AngularJS Service Config value get destroyed on minification

Tags: angularjs, minify

Having some trouble with minification and AngularJS ;-(

I found this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dBR2r/8/) "loading" extender for HTTP request, through the AngularJS Wiki page.

It worked great until i published it, and the minification destroys it.
I can't find a way to use "inject" on the config, so im kinda lost about what to do.

Original code:

```
angular.module("app.services", []).config(function($httpProvider) {
  var spinnerFunction;
  $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push("myHttpInterceptor");
  spinnerFunction = function(data, headersGetter) {
    $("#loader").show();
    return data;
  };
  return $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest.push(spinnerFunction);
}).factory("myHttpInterceptor", function($q, $window) {
  return function(promise) {
    return promise.then((function(response) {
      $("#loader").hide();
      return response;
    }), function(response) {
      $("#loader").hide();
      return $q.reject(response);
    });
  };
});
```

Minified code:

```
angular.module("app.services", []).config(function (a) {
    var b;
    a.responseInterceptors.push("myHttpInterceptor");
    b = function (d, c) {
        $("#loader").show();
        return d
    };
    return a.defaults.transformRequest.push(b)
}).factory("myHttpInterceptor", function (a, b) {
    return function (c) {
        return c.then((function (d) {
            $("#loader").hide();
            return d
        }), function (d) {
            $("#loader").hide();
            return a.reject(d)
        })
    }
});
```

Which throws the following error: 
**Error: Unknown provider: a from app.services**

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use [inline annotation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) for defining providers:

```
angular.module("app.services", [])
  .config(
    [
      '$httpProvider',
      'myHttpInterceptor',
      function($httpProvider, myHttpInterceptor) {
        var spinnerFunction;
        $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(myHttpInterceptor);
        spinnerFunction = function(data, headersGetter) {
         $("#loader").show();
         return data;
        };
        return $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest.push(spinnerFunction);
      }
    ]
  );
```

And, btw, you should reconsider using jQuery calls inside your configs and factories. Direct DOM manipulation should be handled inside the directives.

For your case, instead of `$("#loader").show();` and `$("#loader").show();` you should broadcast an event (e.g. `$rootScope.$broadcast('loader_show')`), and then listen for that event in your custom 'spinner' directive:

HTML:

```
<div spinner class="loader"></div>
```

JS:

```
app.directive('spinner',
    function() {
      return function ($scope, element, attrs) {
        $scope.$on('loader_show', function(){
          element.show();
        });

        $scope.$on('loader_hide', function(){
          element.hide();
        });
      };

    }

  );
```

Comment: Just for clarification, it is actually called "inline annotation".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions ;-)
Im getting the following error, using the code you wrote `Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: myHttpInterceptorProvider <- myHttpInterceptor <- $http <- $compile` got any ideas to what the error is caused by?

Comment: I will definetly try to use ur idea about broadcasting... My goal is to get around jQuery if possible, and atleast not make angular dependent on it.. So ur right, ill definetly look into that ;-)

Comment: Regarding your 'Unknown provider' error - you need to inject your `myHttpInterceptor` the same way I did with `$httpProvider`. I'll update my answer...

Comment: Actually I think it's called inline bracket notation, see here: http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05

Comment: I don't suppose there is an easy way to trace which service this is actually happening to, since it is getting lost in minification.. I have tons of dependencies that aren't using inline annotation but all my code is

Comment: found ng-annotate which dynamically takes care of this

Answer (score 3):

Just for others in the same situation... I followed @Stewie 's advice, and made this instead, which only uses AngularJS code, no stupid jQuery dependency ;-)

**Service:**

```
app.config([
  "$httpProvider", function($httpProvider) {
    var spinnerFunction;
    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push("myHttpInterceptor");
    spinnerFunction = function(data, headersGetter) {
      return data;
    };
    return $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest.push(spinnerFunction);
  }
]).factory("myHttpInterceptor", [
  "$q", "$window", "$rootScope", function($q, $window, $rootScope) {
    return function(promise) {
      $rootScope.$broadcast("loader_show");
      return promise.then((function(response) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast("loader_hide");
        return response;
      }), function(response) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast("loader_hide");
        $rootScope.network_error = true;
        return $q.reject(response);
      });
    };
  }
]);
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive("spinner", function() {
  return function($scope, element, attrs) {
    $scope.$on("loader_show", function() {
      return element.removeClass("hide");
    });
    return $scope.$on("loader_hide", function() {
      return element.addClass("hide");
    });
  };
});
```

Answer (score 3):

As strange as it might seem, you can also use inline annotation where you do the actual `.push()` to inject your dependencies on `$q` and `$window` i.e. instead of pusing a function() into `$httpProvider.responseInterceptors` you push an array:

```
app.config(["$httpProvider", function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(['$q', '$window', function($q, $window) {
        return function(promise) {
            return promise.then(function(response) {
                    $("#loader").hide();
                    return response;
                },
                function(response) {
                    $("#loader").hide();
                    return $q.reject(response);
                });
        };
    }]);
}]);
```